# Rotating logs without restart, multiple process problem

Tags: c++, linux, logging

Here is the deal:
I have a multiple process system (pre-fork model, similar to apache). all processes are writing to the same log file (in fact a binary log file recording requests and responses, but no matter).

I protect against concurrent access to the log via a shared memory lock, and when the file reach a certain size the process that notices it first roll the logs by:

1. closing the file.
2. renaming log.bin -> log.bin.1, log.bin.1 -> log.bin.2 and so on.
3. deleting logs that are beyond the max allowed number of logs. (say, log.bin.10)
4. opening a new log.bin file

The problem is that other processes are unaware, and are in fact continue to write to the old log file (which was renamed to log.bin.1).

I can think of several solutions:

1. some sort of rpc to notify other processes to reopen the log (maybe even a singal). I don't particularly like it.
2. have processes check the file length via the opened file stream, and somehow detect that the file was renamed under them and reopen log.bin file.

None of those is very elegant in my opinion.

thoughts? recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution seems fine, but you should store an integer with inode of current logging file in shared memory  (see [stat(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) with **stat.st_ino** member).

This way, all process kept a local variable with the opened inode file.

The shared var must be updated when rotating by only one process, and all other process are aware by checking a difference between the local inode and the shared inode. It should induce a reopening.

Comment: I am attempting to implement rotation detection based on the difference of the length between the opened file (ftell/tellg) and the size of the current log file on the disk.

it's not 100% bullet proof, but should work in this scenario and does not require any shared memory.

Comment: You are already using shared memory with shared mutex, it is only an integer to use in addition to have a 100% bullet proof :-) IMHO, testing size difference will randomly working and will be headache-prone.

Comment: yes, but it's a trivial boost::interprocess::file_lock. any way, I think this is the best answer because it's results in the most efficient logging and rotation.

Answer (score 2):

You could **copy** log.bin to log.bin.1 and **then truncate** the log.bin file. 
So the problems can still write to the old file pointer, which is empty now.

See also `man logrotate`:

> ```
>    copytruncate
>           Truncate  the original log file to zero size in place after cre‐
>           ating a copy, instead of moving the old log file and  optionally
>           creating  a new one.  It can be used when some program cannot be
>           told to close  its  logfile  and  thus  might  continue  writing
>           (appending)  to  the previous log file forever.  Note that there
>           is a very small time slice between copying the file and truncat‐
>           ing it, so some logging data might be lost.  When this option is
>           used, the create option will have no effect, as the old log file
>           stays in place.
> ```

Comment: that's an option I considered, but since the bin log files are currently set to rotate at 100mb, it will be a pretty expensive rotation. I am looking for a lightweight solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. What about opening the file by name each time before writing a log entry?

   1. get shared memory lock
   2. open file by name
   3. write log entry
   4. close file
   5. release lock
2. Or you could create a logging process, which receives log messages from the other processes and handles all the rotating transparently from them.

Comment: Closing the file after writing the record is a pretty good idea - except it will increase logging overhead. in my case it may be suitable because I only get at most 2-3 logging events / sec.

new logger process will increase system complexity and hurt robustness. I looking for a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what language you're using but your processes should all log to a log process and the log process abstracts the file writing.

```
Logging client1 ->  |
Logging client2 ->  |
Logging client3 ->  | Logging queue (with process lock) -> logging writer -> file roller
Logging client4 ->  |
```

Comment: Problem with that is that if the logging process dies, I get no logs from any of the other processes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using shared memory, and if you know how many processes are using the log file.
You can create an array of flags in shared memory, telling each of the processes that the file has been rotated.  Each process then resets the flag so that it doesn't re-open the file continuously.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about having each thread log to separate files, and another process managing the merging of these logs into a single one?

```
client1 -> cl1.log
client2 -> cl2.log
...

logger (cl1.log, cl2.log, ...) -> cl.log
```

If the logger dies, the process of logging would still occur, and only the merge of updates functionality is lost temporarily.  The logger could be re-started in a very asynchronous mode, even after a lot of messages had accumulated in individual logging queues.  The rotation is simple move-then-replace, based on the file size of individual logs.  This way, [no messages are lost](https://serverfault.com/a/688661).  The logger process would cleanup individual logs.